# Migrating a file or a folder from one repository to another in Documentum

Tags: java, javafx, documentum, dfc

I am working on a `JavaFx` project connected to `Documentum` data storage . And I am trying to configure how to move a file (lets call it file1) placed in a folder (lets call it Folder1) into another folder (lets call it Folder2) . It's worth mentioning that both of the Folders are in the same cabinet . I have implemented the following class :

```
package application;

import com.documentum.com.DfClientX;
import com.documentum.com.IDfClientX;
import com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfDocument;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfFolder;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfSession;
import com.documentum.fc.common.DfException;
import com.documentum.fc.common.DfId;
import com.documentum.operations.IDfMoveNode;
import com.documentum.operations.IDfMoveOperation;

public class Migrate {
    public Migrate(){}
    public String move ( IDfSession mySession,String docId, String destination){
        String str ="";
        try{

              IDfClientX clientx = new DfClientX();

              IDfMoveOperation mo = clientx . getMoveOperation();


              IDfFolder destinationDirectory = mySession . getFolderByPath(destination);

              //Here is the line that causes error
              mo.setDestinationFolderId(destinationDirectory . getObjectId());

              IDfDocument doc = (IDfDocument) mySession . getObject(new DfId(docId));

              IDfMoveNode node = (IDfMoveNode)mo.add(doc);

                 if (mo.execute()) {
                     str= "Move operation successful . ";
                     }
                     else {
                     str = "Move operation failed . ";
                     }
        }catch(DfException e){
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }


    return str;


    }


    }
```

instead of docId I am passing through the r_object_id of the file I am wishing to be moved but I get the following error :

> com.documentum.fc.client.DfFolder___PROXY cannot be cast to
>   com.documentum.fc.client.IDfDocument

Does any one know where my mistake is ? Or where am I doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious, in line

```
IDfDocument doc = (IDfDocument) mySession . getObject(new DfId(docId));
```

the docId parameter represents folder object, not the document object. Do the type check first to be sure and than use either `IDfFolder` or `IDfDocument`. If you're sure that you're moving folder to another folder than just change  `IDfDocument` -> `IDfFolder`.

Comment: I'd like to ask you one more question regarding this . As for the parameter that I have defined called "destination" I need to pass in the path of my destination folder correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure how the moving mechanism works, but sure, you need to specify somewhere where you want to move your objects.